# Interchange element position for smaller devices - bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to interchange the position of two elements, for only `sm` devices.

It is currently like this:

```
 ----------------- -----------------
|        Text        |        Button        |
 ----------------- -----------------
```

I want it to be like this:

```
 ----------------- 
|        Button        |
 -----------------
|        Text        |
 -----------------
```

In the `FIDDLE`, the `Know the status` text should be below `Save` button for `sm` devices.

[FIDDLE HERE](http://www.bootply.com/HTJvacPo0Y)

Comment: Was your issue solved?

Comment: Yes it was resolved....thanks

Comment: Awesome! Glad that worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the column ordering functionality of Bootstrap:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

Here's a pen to show you an example of how this would work:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyNGWL

Notice how the order of the elements is `TEST 1` and then `TEST 2` when side by side. As the breakpoints of the viewport get smaller they switch places and then, as you requested, the `TEST 2` element is stacked *above* the `TEST 1` element when at smallest breakpoint.